# How to get uniform appearance of unicode (HTML entities) in all browsers

Tags: html, unicode, fonts, html-entities

I'm developing a web application. It has buttons to control play/pause/stop etc. I chose to use unicode symbols as it seemed easier and more flexible than using images. The HTML for the buttons looks like this:

```
<button id="pauseButton">&#x23F8;</button>
<button id="playButton">&#x23F5;</button>
<button id="stopButton">&#x23F9;</button>
<button id="startButton">&#x23EE;</button>
<button id="rewindButton">&#x23EA;</button>
<button id="fastforwardButton">&#x23E9;</button>
<button id="endButton">&#x23ED;</button>
```

With some colour added via CSS, on Chrome/Ubuntu, this looks like this:

[image]

On Chrome/MacOS, like this:

[image]

On the Mac:

- the play button is not rendering at all
- it seems to be using images rather than characters, so the CSS colouring has no effect
- to my taste, it looks horrible

I would like the buttons to be rendered the same on all platforms, and to look the way they do in Chrome/Ubuntu. But I don't undertand enough about what's going on.

- Do I need to include a specific font in the application, and use that for the buttons?
- If so, how do I find the font?
- I have encoded the symbols as HTML entities. Should I be specifying them as unicode characters? Maybe that isn't even a valid question, but it demonstrates my current (lack of) understanding!
- Are there browser settings that will foil attempts to make the buttons uniform (I'm thinking of font settings)?

As well as fixing my specific problem, I'd very much appreciate any pointers towards a better general understanding of this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @giacomo-catenazzi for pointing me towards webfonts. I found the following useful:

- [MDN Web fonts tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts)
- [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) for finding out which fonts have glyphs for particular unicodes
- I downloaded the font from https://webfonts.ffonts.net/, but many other sources are available. MDN suggests [fontsquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/)
- [Font squirrel web font generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) - if you have a TTF or OTF font to convert into a webfont

I followed the instructions from MDN, and set up the newly created web font in the CSS:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Symbola';
    src:url('fonts/Symbola.ttf.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/Symbola.ttf.svg#Symbola') format('svg'),
    url('fonts/Symbola.ttf.eot'),
    url('fonts/Symbola.ttf.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'); 
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {
    font-family: Symbola, sans-serif;
}
```

but *this did not work*. 
There was one more hoop to jump through: It seems that `font-family` is not inherited by form elements, although I couldn't find reference to this in the specifications (but I assume it is there somewhere).

This was fixed by:

```css
button {
    font-family: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use a specific font (search for *webfonts*). You will find the relevant information on how to use it (also in this site). You may need to try several fonts, to find what it appeal to you, and which includes all glyphs you want. Browsers will download the font (usually just a range), either from your site or from usual places, and display it. So you have full control.

On the other hand, *uniform appearance* is often a bad thing. If most webpages will display FastForward button in a similar way (and natively) on my specific computer/OS/browser, probably I would expect it. I do not really care how it will look on other computers.  But it is very good to have *uniform appearance* if you look the uniform appearance of all elements in a page (which also requires controls on fonts). Prefer this latter *uniform appearance.*

Note: Unicode is just about semantics of a *character*, not about appearance (*glyphs*), so to control appearance, you need to use a specific font (something *relatively* new, but well supported by all browsers) or to use images (old method).

Comment: Interesting point about *uniform appearance* and native controls. I would usually agree, but the way the buttons are displayed on the Mac, is so much at odds with the design of my particular application,  that I'm sticking to my guns (for now, but maybe I'll see the light)! I found your destinction between semantics and glyphs very useful.